# Hacer Arcos en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un dibujo en java el cual requiere arcos, sin embargo estos me estan costando mucho problema entender en cuanto a sus coordenadas. Quisiera saber como guiarme en el `g.drawArc();` para crear el dibujo que se muestra en mi programa, cuerpo, orejas, etc.

```js
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class Dibujo extends Frame{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Dibujo p=new Dibujo();
      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bienvenido al dibujo de Pikachu");
   }
   public Dibujo()
   {
     
     this.setSize(1366,768);
      setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
      this.setVisible(true);
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
   
   
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.drawLine(50,100,800,100);
      g.drawLine(50,150,800,150);
      g.drawLine(50,200,800,200);
      g.drawLine(50,250,800,250);
      g.drawLine(50,300,800,300);
      g.drawLine(50,350,800,350);
      g.drawLine(50,400,800,400);
      g.drawLine(50,450,800,450);
      g.drawLine(50,500,800,500);
      g.drawLine(50,550,800,550);
      g.drawLine(50,600,800,600);
      g.drawLine(50,650,800,650);
      g.drawLine(100,50,100,700);
      g.drawLine(150,50,150,700);
      g.drawLine(200,50,200,700);
      g.drawLine(250,50,250,700);
      g.drawLine(300,50,300,700);
      g.drawLine(350,50,350,700);
      g.drawLine(400,50,400,700);
      g.drawLine(450,50,450,700);
      g.drawLine(500,50,500,700);
      g.drawLine(550,50,550,700);
      g.drawLine(600,50,600,700);
      g.drawLine(650,50,650,700);
      g.drawLine(700,50,700,700);
      g.drawLine(750,50,750,700);
   
   
   
  
      g.setColor(Color.black);
 
   //COLA
   
      /*cola abajo*/
      g.drawLine(148,370,345,337);
      g.drawLine(148,370,205,505);
      g.drawLine(205,505,280,485);
      g.drawLine(280,485,252,552);
      g.drawLine(252,552,320,557);
      g.drawLine(320,557,301,604);
      g.drawLine(301,604,351,610);
      /*cola arriba*/
      g.drawLine(351,590,340,585);
      g.drawLine(340,585,360,535);
      g.drawLine(360,532,320,520);
      g.drawLine(320,520,330,502);
      /*decoracion cola*/
      g.drawLine(320,560,322,572);
      g.drawLine(322,572,326,560);
      g.drawLine(326,560,328,572);
      g.drawLine(328,572,334,558);
      g.drawLine(334,558,335,571);
      g.drawLine(335,571,345,559);
      g.drawLine(345,559,345,572);
      
      /*orejas*/
    g.drawArc(425, 225, 100, 100, 70, 30);
      
    
   */
   //IMGAGEN ORIGINAL
      super.paint(g);
      Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
      Image imagen = t.getImage ("pikachu.gif");
      g.drawImage (imagen, 750, 50, this);
   
   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

los dos primeros parametros especifica la posicion en donde se dibujara el arco
los siguiente dos parametros son el ancho y el alto, y por los ultimos dos parametros especifica el inicio del arco en grados, y el fin 
ejemplo

```
g.drawArc(425, 225, 100, 100, 0, 30);//30 grados 
         (posX, posY, ancho, alto,inicio de grado, fin de grado)
```